# Graph Theory - Show that if $k$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ and $\delta(G)$ $\ge$ $2k + 1$, then $G$ contains a cycle which has even length and at least $k+2$.

Tags: graph-theory

$a)$ Show that if $\delta(G)$$\ge$$3$, then $G$ contains a cycle which has even length.

$b)$ Show that if $k$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ and $\delta(G)$ $\ge$ $2k + 1$, then $G$ contains a cycle which has even length and at least $k+2$.

I have done part $a)$.

I have seen a similar proof to part $b)$ for cycle of even length and length of at least $2k+2$ but am unsure how i would show it for cycle of even length and length of at least $k+2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_0-v_1-...-v_n$ be the longest path in the graph. Then all points connected to $v_0$ are in this path, since if it some $u$ connected to $v_0$ is not in this path we could get longer path $u-v_0-v_1-...-v_n$.

Now let $v_m$ be the last point in this path which is also connected to $v_0$. 
So we have a cycle $$C: v_0-v_1-...-v_m-v_0$$ which is of lenght $m+1\geq 2k+2$.

If $m$ is odd we are done.

If $m$ is even then let $w$ be the $k+1$-th neighbor of $v_0$ in this path. 
We can thus make two smaller cycles $$C_1: v_0-v_1-...-w-v_0$$ say $|C_1|=a$ and $$C_2: v_0-w-...-v_m-v_0$$ say $|C_2|=b$. Then each cycle is of length at least $k+2$ and one of them is of even length (since $a+b=2m+1$ and so exactly one of $a$ or $b$ is even).